# How to use this EmChart to get perfect font sizes in ems?

Tags: css, xhtml, fonts, font-size

What is the purpose of this chart and how to use?
http://aloestudios.com/tools/emchart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a current font size of the-row-headings, and a wanted font size of the-column-headings, set the font size to the number of ems at the point of intersection.

Of course, you can't know what the user has their default font size set to (although many people assume it is 16px) so it is largely useless.

Comment: Dorward - how to use this tool if my body `{font-size:62.5%}`

Comment: 62.5% of what? The user's preference? Which you don't know? Thus the tool is, as I said "largely useless"

Comment: I believe you have interpreted the chart backwards, given a current font size of 16px and a desired font size of 24px, you need 1.5em, which is row 16px and column 24px.

Comment: @Roger — good catch, my level of attention was a side effect of my level of respect for the "tool" . :)